# why does eclipse autoformat blockcode inconsistently?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Eclipse autoformats blockcode in a negative fashion.

```
//the following code:
/*
this is just blockcode
in 2 lines
*/
```

becomes:

```
/*
 * this is just blockcode
 * in 2 lines
 */
```

The problem with that is the fact that reversing blockcode via

> mark,rightclick menu-> source -> remove block comment

just removes the beginning `/*` and ending `*/` leaving the rest of the code with asterix `*` in front.

I like to program via trial and error, using the `/* */` to block a lot of code and autoformating many times.

The core question is :

***Why can't autoformat detect asterix in front of each line as a leftover from a removed blockcode and remove it by himself?***

I could change blockcode formatting so asterix are not shown at all but that would destroy good commentary for methods/functions.

Comment: I found myself asking that same questions many times. The only solution I found was to disable block-comment formatting.

Comment: *"i could change blockcode formatting so asterix are not shown at all but that would destroy good commentary for methods/functions."*  Why?  I consider the 2nd & 3rd asterisks in the auto-formatted version to be quite redundant.  BTW - Please use your shift key for the first letter of every sentence, as well as for the word 'I'.  This helps the reader.

Comment: but then methods would not have such good looking block comments (tbh this is important to me for understanding my own code and that of others). but if nothing else helps i will do like you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add multi-line block comment..

1. Select the code that you want to comment...Press "Shift+Ctrl+/"
2. To remove either do "Shift+Ctrl+\" OR "mark,rightclick menu-> source -> remove block comment"

And it works fine..!!

Comment: But they'll be mixed with line comments by the formatter, according to the question.

Comment: No they dont..when you select Code that consist of `normal code lines`, `single line comment`, `multi-line block comment` and you do `remove block comment`, only `multi-line block comment` are removed..!!

Comment: yes. maybe my procedure of coding is just bad habit. i block comment "code" and autoformat it. i want to undo that without beeing forced to remove asterixes line after line. if you guys never autoformat while testing this problem does not come up.

Comment: nevermind , ramandeep was right. this circumvents the problem for now! thanks

Comment: So if you use this technique and run the formatter, the line comments wont get messed up?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the behavior you're describing is a bug and needs to be reported to eclipse support. Line comments and block comments shouldn't be converted to block comments.

I've found that selecting a bunch of code and pressing ctrl-slash is a handy way to enable/disable temporary code. That's what I use instead of block comments and I've never been burned by the formatter.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. gonna use this from now on. raman was slightly faster, sry! gonna report to eclipse anyway.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=67286 already posted and known since 2004. seems like they will never change this habit.